# Can we use grid lines to align shapes or images in powerpoint using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can we use grid lines to align shapes or images in PowerPoint using VBA?
Are there any properties which are related to grid line?

Comment: Do you mean grid or guidelines?  Guidelines aren't exposed via the OM, so you can't get at them via code (other than via XML; guide positions are there in the XML).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg : Yes, I mean gridlines. Its option appears in View tab in powerpoint 2007

Answer (score 0):

The grid distance can be found in `Presentation.GridDistance`. I think it's always centered on the slide so you can expect to have grid lines at `Presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 2` and `Presentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2`. But I am not aware of any other properties or methods so you would have to do your own calculations in order to determine the other grid lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to find out other properties based on your provided properties.